# How can I create dependent category and subcategory drop down menus?

Tags: drop-down-menu

How can I create dependent drop-down menus for category and subcategory, where the subcategory's options are dependent upon what is selected in the category menu? I am creating an e-commerce store. On the admin side I would like to have the user enter products.  I am using a form that includes select options for "category" and "subcategory", but I can't find any tutorials or forums that address this specifically.

Comment: both tags looks incorrect here.

Comment: well they're not, thank you.

Comment: Please clarify bit more in your question.  In current shape, it will be closed as _unclear_